# After upload redirect to URL

Tags: jquery

Trying to redirect page after uploading a file
http://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/sfuon5y6/8/

```
$("#upload_link.first").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
});

/*
  $("#upload_link.first").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
  },
  function(){
      window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
  });
*/
```

Comment: so what was the issue?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama, on click it redirects but I need fist it should complete upload step and then redirect.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the on change event of the file input field

```
$("#upload_link.first").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
});
$('#upload:hidden').change(function(e){
      console.log(e.target.files[0])
      window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/740kr2p1/

Comment: Wont that redirect user as soon as he clicked upload? Not necessarily if he successfully uploaded file.